# jQuery - select function is not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made an OTP design. So I have 6 inputs and everytime the user types a number it will go automatically to the next input. I have made the code below but the `.select()` is not working on mobile phones. Can someone help me with this?

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/aceraven777/pen/wvmbadQ

**HTML**

```html
<div class="otp-group">
    <div class="otp-digit otp-digit-1">
        <input type="text" class="input-text" autocomplete="on" aria-label="-" placeholder="-" aria-required="false" maxlength="1" pattern="\d*">
    </div>

    <div class="otp-digit otp-digit-2">
        <input type="text" class="input-text" autocomplete="on" aria-label="-" placeholder="-" aria-required="false" maxlength="1" pattern="\d*">
    </div>

    <div class="otp-digit otp-digit-3">
        <input type="text" class="input-text" autocomplete="on" aria-label="-" placeholder="-" aria-required="false" maxlength="1" pattern="\d*">
    </div>

    <div class="otp-digit otp-digit-4">
        <input type="text" class="input-text" autocomplete="on" aria-label="-" placeholder="-" aria-required="false" maxlength="1" pattern="\d*">
    </div>

    <div class="otp-digit otp-digit-5">
        <input type="text" class="input-text" autocomplete="on" aria-label="-" placeholder="-" aria-required="false" maxlength="1" pattern="\d*">
    </div>

    <div class="otp-digit otp-digit-6">
        <input type="text" class="input-text" autocomplete="on" aria-label="-" placeholder="-" aria-required="false" maxlength="1" pattern="\d*">
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```js
$('.otp-digit').each(function() {
    var $otp_digit = $(this);
    var $input = $otp_digit.find('input');

    $input.attr('maxlength', 1);
    $input.attr('pattern', '\\d*');

    $input.on('keyup', function(e) {
        var $input = $(this);
        var $otp_digit = $input.closest('.otp-digit');
        var $prev_otp_digit = $otp_digit.prev();
        var $next_otp_digit = $otp_digit.next();

        // Backspace or left arrow key
        if (e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 37) {
            if ($prev_otp_digit.length && $prev_otp_digit.hasClass('otp-digit')) {
                $prev_otp_digit.find('input').select().focus();
            }
        }
        // Right arrow and numbers
        else if (e.keyCode === 39 || (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105)) {
            if ($next_otp_digit.length && $next_otp_digit.hasClass('otp-digit')) {
                $next_otp_digit.find('input').select().focus();
            }
        }

        // Backspace
        if (e.keyCode === 8) {
            $input.val('');
        }
        else if ((e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105)) {
            var characterCode = ((96 <= e.keyCode && e.keyCode <= 105)? e.keyCode - 48 : e.keyCode);
            $input.val(String.fromCharCode(characterCode));
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });

    $input.on('keypress', function(e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

        // Allow only typing numbers
        if (keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    });

    $input.on("change",function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var input_value = $this.val().replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');

        $this.val(input_value);
        
        var $form = $this.closest('.gigya-otp-login-form');
        var $inputs = $form.find('.otp-digit input');
        var otp_code = '';

        $inputs.each(function() {
            otp_code += $(this).val();
        });
    });

    $input.on("cut copy paste",function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

If the jQuery `.select()` or segmenting it into multiple input isn't possible, maybe someone can give me an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forked your code **[here](https://codepen.io/hncvj/pen/zYWVEpG)** and made some changes. Here are those changes:

1. Changed input type **text** to **number**:
2. Added CSS to hide the arrow keys of number inputs.

There are no changes in JS.

**HTML**

```
<div class="otp-group">
    <div class="otp-digit otp-digit-1">
        <input type="number" class="input-text" autocomplete="on" aria-label="-" placeholder="-" aria-required="false" maxlength="1" pattern="\d*">
    </div>

    <div class="otp-digit otp-digit-2">
        <input type="number" class="input-text" autocomplete="on" aria-label="-" placeholder="-" aria-required="false" maxlength="1" pattern="\d*">
    </div>

    <div class="otp-digit otp-digit-3">
        <input type="number" class="input-text" autocomplete="on" aria-label="-" placeholder="-" aria-required="false" maxlength="1" pattern="\d*">
    </div>

    <div class="otp-digit otp-digit-4">
        <input type="number" class="input-text" autocomplete="on" aria-label="-" placeholder="-" aria-required="false" maxlength="1" pattern="\d*">
    </div>

    <div class="otp-digit otp-digit-5">
        <input type="number" class="input-text" autocomplete="on" aria-label="-" placeholder="-" aria-required="false" maxlength="1" pattern="\d*">
    </div>

    <div class="otp-digit otp-digit-6">
        <input type="number" class="input-text" autocomplete="on" aria-label="-" placeholder="-" aria-required="false" maxlength="1" pattern="\d*">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Extra CSS**

```
/* Add CSS to hide number arrows */
/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Firefox */
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

By making these changes my mobile device started showing the number pad instead of a full keyboard which is a better UX for OTP inputs and your code already takes care to allow only numeric inputs so it's a win-win.

I didn't like the arrow keys so I kept them hidden using CSS. I'm not sure if that CSS works on iOS devices cause you might know safari doesn't support a lot of things in CSS.

And Voila! it started working on my phone.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Well it works on the mobile now. My question now is why does it work when we use type **number**? Because I thought the issue was on jQuery `.select()` function.

Comment: I added logs and checked when it was in text. I found out that it does hit all of the if conditions and next() and prev() too. But somehow it works only with input type number and numpad but not full keyboard. Also, luckily i happen to have same situation in one of my projects recently so i thought i can solve this for you and hence the solution came across.

Comment: I also actually put `console.log` to investigate what is wrong, yea we actually have the same result. So if we do this on a non-numeric input such as alphabets, this solution won't work. Anyway this solves my problem for now, thank you!